# What is the temperature of heat generated from LPG gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat, combustion, hydrocarbons, fuel

I'm working on a project and I require around 300-400 degree Celsius of temperature. As of now I'm taking the normal LPG gas that is available in our house for cooking purposes for my project, but I'm not sure whether it can reach 300-400 degree Celsius or not? I can definitely use multiple burners but how much heat/temperature does 1 burner generate?

Maybe I'm wrong because heat is counted in calorific value, but then how do we know the temperature of that calorific value? Or is there some relation which says that x amount of LPG would give x degree Celsius or maybe x calorific value? But yet again, how can I know the temperature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LPG is mostly propane and butane both of which have adiabatic flame temperature near 1970 degrees C when burned in air.  See [Flame Temperatures of some Common Gases](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/flame-temperatures-gases-d_422.html).

So 300-400 degrees C is certainly reachable.

Comment: That looks promising, but here comes one contradiction (I may be wrong), when you heat water on your stove, it takes around a minute or so in order for evaporation to start which takes place at 100C. Now if that can take around a minute,  then how can it be 1970C flame temperature? Or is the rest of the heat getting used up by the pan in which water is being heated?

Comment: Because the time it takes for a material being heated to reach a certain temperature, is a function of the amount of material, the heat capacity of the material and the rate of heat transfer to the material (including both heating mechanisms and cooling mechanism; for example the water could be getting heated from below and cold from above).

Comment: I wonder that is there any way to find out that "time" that heat would take for its transfer in that material?

Comment: in what material?

Comment: The material that I'll be using would be Stainless Steel. Or is there any formula to find "time" in any material? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: OK, the heat capacity of stainless steel is 500 Joule per kg per degree C.  But that is only one piece of the puzzle.  If I put a stainless steel needle into a gas stove flame to sterilize it to get a splinter out of my skin, the tip of the needle glows orange within one second, meaning it is over 1500 degrees C.  You will need to consider amount of material, surface area, and the temperature all surface are exposed to, and a heat transfer coeffient.  Read about newton's law of cooling: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convective_heat_transfer

Comment: Really, thanks a lot! BTW I'm working on a project, so if it doesn't bother you then can you share your mail address or facebook's username with me?